# How can I pass local variables between doGet and doPost method in Servlet?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I understand that in order to write Thread-Safe servlets one of the easiest thing is to declare all variables locally.

When my program calls doPost it creates an instance of a database lets call it db. I want to pass that instance to the doGet method but securely without having to declare db globally. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Why would you call doGet() from doPost()?

Comment: I don't call it from doPost() I want to instantiate the database once and use that instance in the program.

Comment: You say you don't want to declare it "globally" (there is no such thing in Java, that's a C term) but you want some kind of singleton - that sounds like a contradiction to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a class variable that references a DataSource object from which you could get new fresh connection to your database either in your doGet or doPost methods. This is a tread-safe manner.

But for a better maintainability of your code, you should read about [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, doGet() and doPost() are called in different situations (when the browser or HTTP client executes a GET or POST HTTP request, respectively).

It sounds like your application has functionality in common between those two requests. My recommendation is that you abstract that shared functionality into another method (or methods) within your servlet that both doGet() and doPost() can call.

Alternatively, if *all* functionality is shared, you can instead implement the service() method, which the servlet container will call for all request types (instead of doGet() or doPost()).